# Does UFD imply ACC?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

UFD imply ACCP (ascending chain condition for principal ideals). But is it necessarily UFD implies ACC also (ascending chain condition for ideals)?

Comment: If it were so, you'd probably have seen a theorem stating it. So guess that there are UFDs that aren't Noetherian. Where you should first look for (counter)examples depends on your background.

Comment: Is there a reason for deleting the [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446144/ufd-and-ascending-chain-conditions) after someone answered one of your questions and after I gave you a link where you could find the example given below?

Answer (score 6):

No. If $K$ is a field, $K[X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n,\dots]$  is an example of a non-noetherian UFD.